# Should it be names of places/name of places

Tags: plural-forms, grammatical-number, grammaticality-in-context

I can't figure which one is grammatically correct.

> The **names** of the places I visited in the country are...
>   The **name** of the places I visited in the country are...

Comment: "Places" are in the plural, so it should be "**names**".

Comment: P.S. Although I've found several instances of "the name of the places" at Google Books, they probably differ a bit in meaning from your intended statement.

Comment: @CopperKettle I think those are cases where the subject is a general or group term, for example "What is the name of the places were the tectonic plates meet?". The answer might be *A plate boundary" but this does not indicate a specific name of one place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use *name* only if all the places had the same name (not really possible).
Since there will be more than one name involved, you have to use *names*:

> The names of the places I visited in the country are...